# Extracting A String Between Two Characters in Bash

Tags: regex, linux, bash, sed, grep

I need help with extracting a string between the "@" symbol and a space " " in Bash.

I'm using Python Twitter Tools, and the output is like this:

```
430438229200740352 2014-02-03 14:30:45 CST <HorizonAwon> @SawBlastt @WereAutomatic 101 for me to join as well
```

I need to extract the two strings:

> SawBlastt
>
> WereAutomatic

I also need to set them each as a separate variable.  I've tried messing around with sed and grep, but no successful results.  I'm really stuck on this.  Help is very appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use:

```
s='430438229200740352 2014-02-03 14:30:45 CST <HorizonAwon> @SawBlastt @WereAutomatic 101 for me to join as well'
grep -oP '@\K[^ ]*' <<< "$s"
SawBlastt
WereAutomatic
```

Comment: Since you're using `-P`, you might as well use `\w+` instead of `[^ ]*`

Comment: Yes sure that can also be used but I wasn't sure if dot or hyphen won't be there between `@` and `" "`

Comment: +1; to those (like me) unfamiliar with `\K`: this Perl[-style] regex feature (available thanks to the `-P` `grep` option) causes the string matched so far to be dropped and thus is a simpler alternative to a look-behind expression (which, in this case, would be `grep -oP '(?<=@)[^ ]*'`).

Answer (score 3):

Another gnu grep command, that I used mostly.

```
grep -Po "(?<=@)[^ ]*" file
```

Answer (score 1):

BASH has its own regex matching capabilities that will work.

```
s="430438229200740352 2014-02-03 14:30:45 CST <HorizonAwon> @SawBlastt @WereAutomatic 101 for me to join as well"
if [[ $s =~ @([A-Za-z]+)\ @([A-Za-z]+) ]]; then
    echo ${BASH_REMATCH[1]} ${BASH_REMATCH[2]}
fi
```

To explain, here's what `man bash` says:

> The  element  of BASH_REMATCH with index n is the portion of the string matching the nth parenthesized subexpression.

Answer (score 0):

This sets variable like OP requested

```
$ cat foo.txt
430438229200740352 2014-02-03 14:30:45 CST <HorizonAwon> @SawBlastt @WereAutomatic 101 for me to join as well

$ set $(awk '{print $6,$7}' FS='[ @]+' foo.txt)

$ echo $1 $2
SawBlastt WereAutomatic
```